# plotly choropleth showing half-ish of the map?

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I am trying to plot a choropleth map of the municipalities of a specific province in Spain. I am running the script in Jupyter Notebook. I am using a csv file for data import from that specific province and the json file is for all the municipalities in Spain.
As a result, only about a third of the municipalities are plotted, and I do get the values for the remaining municipalities, which are not plotted on the map, when I hover the mouse over them. What could be the issue?

Edit: this is the link to download the json file with the original conflicting municipality coordinates reversed:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/189gyo03E7D3icPHZeukaerACXQOcx8wI/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("result.csv",sep=";")

fig=px.choropleth(df, geojson="data\\gadm36_ESP_4.json",
                               featureidkey='properties.NAME_4',   
             locations='CityName',        #column in dataframe
              #animation_frame='Year',       #dataframe
              color='Value',  #dataframe
              color_continuous_scale='sunset',
               title='Expected Output' , 
               height=700
              )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.show()
```

And this is the map I am getting (which shows the value for an "invisible" city):

[image]

Finally if I could get any hints as to how to change the background to grey or similar, I tried

```
fig.update_layout(geo=dict(bgcolor= 'rgba(173,157,157,1)'))
```

but didn't make any difference.
Any help is much appreciated.

For reference, I have also created a simple plot with the same json file and I do ge all the borders. See below.

[image]

Comment: Rather than changing the background, why not change the discrete color set?

Comment: Initially I had the color_continous_scale parameter set to "Inferno" but the background seems always to color itself fully with a color in the low range of the values, like this "pale orange"

Comment: This is just a guess, but there may be a possibility that the polygon information in the JSON file is not closed. How about using this as a clue to isolate the problem?

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners Actually I created a simple plot with geopandas and  I do get the full distribution of municipalities. I attach it to the original post for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your map and the background color have the same root cause- one or more shapes in your geojson is causing plotly to interpret the coordinates as being inverted so that it fills everything *except* the offending shape. In your map I would suspect the white colored municipality is causing the issue.

One possible solution is to reverse the coordinates of the offending shape.

Comment: Thanks ever so mucho for your suggestion @zerOpRiME. When you say "reverse the coordinates", do you mean from a set of coordinates like [[102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0]] reverse them to [[104.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [102.0, 0.0]]?

Comment: Yes, try that and share what happens- also, let me know if the data is available on git to download, I can take a look myself.

Comment: Thanks @zerOpRiME, that worked, I managed to move forth a bit! It seems that there are some other conflicting municipalities. I am modifying the original post to include a link to download the json file from my gdrive. I tried reversing one of them ("Güeñes") but this made the map again filling in reversed, so in this case the coordinate list seems to be in the right direction but it is not well formed. Another of the big gaps is "Mungia" which is of MultiPolygon type, so reversing is not that straight forward, is it?